# Understanding Casting in Java

Tags: java, casting, floating-point, double, precision

this is my first post here and i like to thank all the people that can help me with this simple question: how the casting works in java?

I made this very simple class:

```
public class test {
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println((short)(1/3));
        System.out.println((int)(1/3));
        System.out.println((float)(1/3));
        System.out.println((double)(1/3));
    }
}
```

and this piece of software gives me this output when executed ( official JDK 6 u26 on a 32 bit machine under linux )

```
0
0
0.0
0.0
```

the problem, or the thing that i don't understand if you would, is that the last 2 results are 0.0, i was expecting something like 0.3333333, but apparently the cast works in another way: how?

thanks

PS
I'm not so familiar with the english language, if i made some errors i apologize for this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, the expression `1/3` is executed. This expression means "integer division of 1 by 3". And its result is the integer `0`. Then this result (`0`) is cast to a double (or float). And of course it leads to `0.0`.

You must cast one of the operands of the division to a double (or float) to transform it into a double division:

```
double d = ((double) 1) / 3;
```

or simply write

```
1.0 / 3
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use the operator `/` on integer values, the result will be typed as an integer.

You will have to force either 1 or 3 to a floating point value - try writing `1.0/3` instead of `1/3`.

Answer (score 4):

In the last 2 cases you first compute 1/3, which is 0. Then you cast it to a float/double.
Use:

```
((float)1)/3
```

Answer (score 1):

int is coverted into double.

(1/3) is of type int so answer will be 0.

Now 0 is casted to double or float so it has become 0.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the operands, not the result. This will yield the output you expected:

```
System.out.println(((short) 1 / (short) 3));
System.out.println((1 / 3));
System.out.println(((float) 1 / (float) 3));
System.out.println(((double) 1 / (double) 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have the 1/3 in parentheses, it uses integer division then casts to the type specified. It would evaluate to .3333333 if you used 1.0/3.0 or (float)1/3. 1 and 3 are integer literals, so results from division will be truncated. To use float and double literals put an f or d at the end of the number (1.0f, 1.0d). Casting affects the value after it, so if your value is in parentheses, it will evaluate that, then make the cast.